# Bootsrap 4 collapsible div clearfix issue

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4, grid

This is Bootstrap 4 cards with collapsible divs. When click to "list button" it opens collapsible div on right column but on the left side push the content to bottom.

How can I resolve the whitespace issue?

I add "clearfix" div after each pair of column but still doesn't work.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6">
    <div id="accordion1">
      <!-- Products -->
      <div class="card mb-3">
        <!--Lock Products-->
        <div class="overlock text-center align-baseline d-none">
          <i class="mdi mdi-lock display-4 alignico"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="row no-gutters">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title text-info"><i class="mdi mdi-lifebuoy text-info"></i> test1</h5>
              <p class="card-text text-muted">list</p>
              <button class="btn btn-outline-info btn-block" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#product1SubProducts"><i class="mdi mdi-folder-open"></i> list </button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <a id="banner" href="#" target="_blank">
              <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/300x52/?family" class="card-img" alt="Product 1 Banner">
            </a>
            <div class="card-body pt-0">
              <small class="text-muted"><i class="mdi mdi-information-outline"></i> text: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</small>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="collapse p-3" id="product1SubProducts" data-parent="#accordion1">
          <!-- Sub-Products -->
          <div class="card mb-3 sub-products">
            <div class="card-body p-0">
              <h5 class="card-title border-bottom pb-1 text-muted"><i class="mdi mdi-view-grid-plus"></i> item</h5>
              <div class="tariffs">
                <div class="input-group">
                  <select class="custom-select" id="inputGroupSelect04">
                    <option value="" selected>choose</option>
                    <option value="2">trf-1</option>
                    <option value="2">trf-2</option>
                  </select>
                  <div class="input-group-append">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button">go</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          
          <!-- Sub-Products -->
          <div class="card mb-3 sub-products">
            <div class="card-body p-0">
              <h5 class="card-title border-bottom pb-1 text-muted"><i class="mdi mdi-view-grid-plus"></i> Geleceğe Yatırım <sup class="badge badge-success" style="font-size:.7rem;font-weight:normal">YENİ</sup></h5>
              <div class="tariffs">
                <div class="input-group">
                  <select class="custom-select" id="inputGroupSelect04">
                    <option value="" selected>choose</option>
                    <option value="2">trf-1</option>
                    <option value="2">trf-2</option>
                  </select>
                  <div class="input-group-append">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button">go</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div style="clear:both"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-6">
    <div id="accordion2">
      <!-- Products -->
      <div class="card mb-3">
        <!--Lock Products-->
        <div class="overlock text-center align-baseline d-none">
          <i class="mdi mdi-lock display-4 alignico"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="row no-gutters">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title text-info"><i class="mdi mdi-lifebuoy text-info"></i> test2</h5>
              <p class="card-text text-muted">list</p>
              <button class="btn btn-outline-info btn-block" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#product2SubProducts"><i class="mdi mdi-folder-open"></i> list </button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <a id="banner" href="#" target="_blank">
              <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/300x52/?family" class="card-img" alt="Product 2 Banner">
            </a>
            <div class="card-body pt-0">
              <small class="text-muted"><i class="mdi mdi-information-outline"></i> text: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</small>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="collapse p-3" id="product2SubProducts" data-parent="#accordion2">
          <!-- Sub-Products -->
          <div class="card mb-3 sub-products">
            <div class="card-body p-0">
              <h5 class="card-title border-bottom pb-1 text-muted"><i class="mdi mdi-view-grid-plus"></i> items</h5>
              <div class="tariffs">
                <div class="input-group">
                  <select class="custom-select" id="inputGroupSelect04">
                    <option value="" selected>choose</option>
                    <option value="2">trf-1</option>
                    <option value="2">trf-2</option>
                  </select>
                  <div class="input-group-append">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button">go</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          
          <!-- Sub-Products -->
          <div class="card mb-3 sub-products">
            <div class="card-body p-0">
              <h5 class="card-title border-bottom pb-1 text-muted"><i class="mdi mdi-view-grid-plus"></i> item <sup class="badge badge-success" style="font-size:.7rem;font-weight:normal">new</sup></h5>
              <div class="tariffs">
                <div class="input-group">
                  <select class="custom-select" id="inputGroupSelect04">
                    <option value="" selected>choose</option>
                    <option value="2">trf-1</option>
                    <option value="2">trf-2</option>
                  </select>
                  <div class="input-group-append">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button">go</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-6">
    <div id="accordion1">
      <!-- Products -->
      <div class="card mb-3">
        <!--Lock Products-->
        <div class="overlock text-center align-baseline d-none">
          <i class="mdi mdi-lock display-4 alignico"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="row no-gutters">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title text-info"><i class="mdi mdi-lifebuoy text-info"></i> test3</h5>
              <p class="card-text text-muted">list</p>
              <button class="btn btn-outline-info btn-block" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#product3SubProducts"><i class="mdi mdi-folder-open"></i> list </button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <a id="banner" href="#" target="_blank">
              <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/300x52/?family" class="card-img" alt="Product 1 Banner">
            </a>
            <div class="card-body pt-0">
              <small class="text-muted"><i class="mdi mdi-information-outline"></i> text: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</small>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="collapse p-3" id="product3SubProducts" data-parent="#accordion1">
          <!-- Sub-Products -->
          <div class="card mb-3 sub-products">
            <div class="card-body p-0">
              <h5 class="card-title border-bottom pb-1 text-muted"><i class="mdi mdi-view-grid-plus"></i> test</h5>
              <div class="tariffs">
                <div class="input-group">
                  <select class="custom-select" id="inputGroupSelect04">
                    <option value="" selected>choose</option>
                    <option value="2">trf-1</option>
                    <option value="2">trf-2</option>
                  </select>
                  <div class="input-group-append">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button">go</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          
          <!-- Sub-Products -->
          <div class="card mb-3 sub-products">
            <div class="card-body p-0">
              <h5 class="card-title border-bottom pb-1 text-muted"><i class="mdi mdi-view-grid-plus"></i> item <sup class="badge badge-success" style="font-size:.7rem;font-weight:normal">new</sup></h5>
              
              <div class="tariffs">
                <div class="input-group">
                  <select class="custom-select" id="inputGroupSelect04">
                    <option value="" selected>choose</option>
                    <option value="2">trf-1</option>
                    <option value="2">trf-2</option>
                  </select>
                  <div class="input-group-append">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button">go</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-6">
    <div id="accordion2">
      <!-- Products -->
      <div class="card mb-3">
        <!--Lock Products-->
        <div class="overlock text-center align-baseline d-none">
          <i class="mdi mdi-lock display-4 alignico"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="row no-gutters">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title text-info"><i class="mdi mdi-lifebuoy text-info"></i> test4</h5>
              <p class="card-text text-muted">List</p>
              <button class="btn btn-outline-info btn-block" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#product4SubProducts"><i class="mdi mdi-folder-open"></i> list </button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <a id="banner" href="#" target="_blank">
              <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/300x52/?family" class="card-img" alt="Product 2 Banner">
            </a>
            <div class="card-body pt-0">
              <small class="text-muted"><i class="mdi mdi-information-outline"></i> text: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</small>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse p-3" id="product4SubProducts" data-parent="#accordion2">
          <!-- Sub-Products -->
          <div class="card mb-3 sub-products">
            <div class="card-body p-0">
              <h5 class="card-title border-bottom pb-1 text-muted"><i class="mdi mdi-view-grid-plus"></i> text</h5>
              <div class="tariffs">
                <div class="input-group">
                  <select class="custom-select" id="inputGroupSelect04">
                    <option value="" selected>choose</option>
                    <option value="2">trf-1</option>
                    <option value="2">trf-2</option>
                  </select>
                  <div class="input-group-append">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button">go</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- Sub-Products -->
          <div class="card mb-3 sub-products">
            <div class="card-body p-0">
              <h5 class="card-title border-bottom pb-1 text-muted"><i class="mdi mdi-view-grid-plus"></i> text <sup class="badge badge-success" style="font-size:.7rem;font-weight:normal">YENİ</sup></h5>
              <div class="tariffs">
                <div class="input-group">
                  <select class="custom-select" id="inputGroupSelect04">
                    <option value="" selected>choose</option>
                    <option value="2">trf-1</option>
                    <option value="2">trf-2</option>
                  </select>
                  <div class="input-group-append">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button">go</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Fy6S3B9q64WdZWQUiU+q4/2Lc9npb8tCaSX9FK7E8HnRr0Jz8D6OP9dO5Vg3Q9ct" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Expanding the content increases the height of the row containing two columns. What do you expect? If you don't want that, don't use rows in your layout.

Comment: just copy code and paste into codepen click list btn to expand and collapse col you will  see the whitespace @isherwood <code>https://codepen.io/brusky/pen/bGzOYNR</code>

Comment: I see the whitespace. No need to copy and paste or send us elsewhere--the demo here shows it just fine (better in full page mode).  That doesn't explain your expectations, though. How can a row be a row if it doesn't contain its columns?